# Laravel group routing with parameter

Tags: laravel-5

I have this group in my route:
}

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1/en'], function() {}
```

is it possible to change the 'en' segment uri in a parameter, so it can be changed depending on the request? Something like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1/{lang}'], function() {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about to generate dynamically another route group with prefix `$lang` inside of group with `v1` prefix?

```
$langs = ['en', 'de', 'it'];

Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function() use ($langs) {
  foreach($langs AS $lang) :

    Route::group(['prefix' => $lang], function() {

      Route::get('something', 'SomethingController@list');

    });

  endforeach;
});
```

or same logic (taken from [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/route-group-with-parameter)):

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function() use ($langs) {
    Route::group(['prefix' => '{lang}'], function() {
      Route::get('something', 'SomethingController@list');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, `$lang` will be available if you define your route group like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1/{lang}'], function() {
    // ...
});
```

or with new syntax:

```
Route::prefix('v1/{lang}')->group(function() {
    // ...
});
```

You can access it anywhere with:

```
request()->route()->parameter('lang');
```

---

You might want to checkout packages like this: [Localization for Laravel](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization)

They basically do the same, and have nice middleware implementations to set locales etc.

Comment: my lang is not a parameter, is a uri part like v1/en

Comment: If you make it like `'v1/{lang}'` it is?